# Transfer half of balance?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I have a smart contract which  balance is very dynamic. 
Is there a way to transfer just half of the balance?

I tried:

`account[4].transfer(this.balance / 2);`

I think it's not the greatest idea since number of ether may not be divisible by 2

Comment: I forgot to mention or maybe I am not expressing myself very well: it obviously works but will I meet any problems such as not being able to divide by 2?

Comment: why would ethers not be divisible by 2 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the number of ETH by two.

In Solidity, there are [no fixed-point/floating-point numbers](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals), so you can't return a number like 2.5, but you can use one up until the point where you try to store it in an integer.

In your case, if the contract held 5 ETH, solidity would computer this as sending 2 ETH to `account[4]`.

Example:

`account[4].transfer(5 / 2);` == `account[4].transfer(2);`

Comment: Note that with solidity, unless your contract is dealing with wei, it is pretty unusual to have a number not divisible by 2 at an ether level. 5 ETH is actually 5*10^18 wei, which will divide by 2 quite nicely.